# How can I return a reference to a sub-element of a nested entry in a structure?

Tags: rust, ownership

I have structure with a vector of other structures:

```
pub struct StructB {
    value1: u64,
    value2: String,
}

pub struct StructA {
    array: Vec<StructB>,
}
```

`StructB` is constant; during the creation of `StructA`, an `array` is filled with the objects that are read from a file and is unlikely to be modified.

I would like to have a function to get element `StructB` corresponding to an input parameter: `get_structB(input: u64) -> &StructB`. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that we will just return element with the given index, assuming that someone else is checking boundaries.

I struggle with how to implement that in Rust. I would like to return a kind of "read only" reference or a reference to an object that is immutable but not doing a copy. I cannot figure out the proper way to do that.

```
impl StructA {
    fn get_structB(&self, idx: u64) -> Box<StructB> {   // Or should I use here Rc?
        // Here I don't want to consume self just return reference wrapped to the idx element
        // Should I implement something like as_ref() for the StructA?
        self.array[idx]     // That of course won't compile
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `fn get_structB(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&StructB> { self.array.get(idx) }`?

Comment: @hellow, He may want to send that variable into some thread which wants to own the data itself maybe. Rc can be useful in such scenario

Comment: Doesn't matter. As long as you only want read only access you can pass around `&StructB`. `RC` is not needed here IMHO.

Comment: Yes I think Option to reference should be ok here. Just number of different Rust Wrappers makes me think many times what should be used where. And option gave me some associations with things Enum like? So That is why I started thinking with something like smart pointers.

Comment: @Mazeryt Use `Rc`/`Arc` when there isn't a definitive "owner" of the object. It will feel more OO because it's essentially adding a simple GC.

Comment: @PeterHall  There may be multiple owners of this method and potentially catch the same object by more than one consumers. Will Option be still OK here?

Answer (score 0):

```rust
impl StructA {
    fn get_structB(&self, i: usize) -> &StructB {
        return &self.array[i];
    }
}
```

This does the trick. However, you may encounter some problem if you write the following:

```rust
// `a` is a StructA instance
let bb = a.get_struct_b(0);
println!("{:?}", bb);
drop(a);              // move out of `a` occurs here
println!("{:?}", bb); // borrow of `a` is used here
```

You will have to modify your struct definition and use `Rc` to write the function. `Rc` introduces a little performance impact and makes the code more complex, so you may want to use it only when you know that the data will be used after moving `StructA`.

```rust
pub struct StructA {
    array: Vec<Rc<StructB>>,
}

impl StructA {
    fn get_structB(&self, i: usize) -> Rc<StructB> {
        return Rc::clone(self.array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, it is not idiomatic Rust to use an explicit `return` at the end of a block.